# Can I use KafkaTemplate with singleton scope?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is it right way to wire `org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate` in spring context as singleton, or may I use prototype scope?

Singleton example:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class IntegrationService {
    private final KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendToConsumerService(Dto dto) {
        AvroDto avroDto = convertToAvro(dto);
        try {
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<Object, GenericRecord>> sendResultListenableFuture
                    = kafkaTemplate.send("consumer-topic",
                    TopicKeys.getTopicKey("consumer-topic", avroDto),
                    avroDto);
            if (sendResultListenableFuture.isDone()) {
                log.debug("Sent message to Kafka: {}", avroDto)
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Error sending message to Kafka", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is related to the class name KafkaTemplate.
It seems to me that there should be a new instance for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you need a new instance for each request? A single instance is normally all you need - in fact, even if you use multiple instances, the same underlying Kafka `Producer` is used (by default).

Comment: Because its name template, not KafkaMessageService or ...Sender. I thought like String template. 
Ok, thank you.

Comment: @Gary Russel .If  I am using Transactional  Producer and 2 users are trying to initiate the transaction at the same time then would it work.Don't we need 2 instance of Kafka Producer?Kindly see my question here and if you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037127/multiple-kafka-producer-instance-for-each-http-request