# Multiple Kafka Producer Instance for each Http Request

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a rest end point which can be invoked by multiple users at same time. This rest end point invokes a Transactional Kafka Producer.
What I understand is I cant use same Kafka Producer instance at same time if we use Transaction.

How can I  create a new Kafka Producer Instance for each HTTP request efficiently ?

```
//Kafka Transaction enabled
producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "prod-1-" );

@Service
public class ProducerService {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    public void postMessage(final MyUser message) {
        // wrapping the send method in a transaction
        this.kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kafkaTemplate -> {
              kafkaTemplate.send("custom", null, message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the javadocs for the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`. It maintains a cache of producers for producer-initiated transactions.

```java
/**
 * The {@link ProducerFactory} implementation for a {@code singleton} shared {@link Producer} instance.
 * <p>
 * This implementation will return the same {@link Producer} instance (if transactions are
 * not enabled) for the provided {@link Map} {@code configs} and optional {@link Serializer}
 * implementations on each {@link #createProducer()} invocation.

...

 * Setting {@link #setTransactionIdPrefix(String)} enables transactions; in which case, a
 * cache of producers is maintained; closing a producer returns it to the cache. The
 * producers are closed and the cache is cleared when the factory is destroyed, the
 * application context stopped, or the {@link #reset()} method is called.

...

 */
```

Comment: Russel. Great thanks. So what I  understand .that  I don't need to create   new   Producer for each Http request. Even if 2 HTTP request tries to initiate a Kafka Transaction at the same time then `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` will take care of it .

Comment: Yes, it is all taken care of by the framework. As with all Spring projects, this allows you to concentrate on you business logic rather than these low level nuances.

Comment: By the way, if all you are doing in each transaction is sending a single message, and doing nothing else, why use transactions at all?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for  implementing it .Just one last question  when  will the transactional producer instances that are not used will be closed  and how many caches of producer will be maintained.  I have seen few questions on stack where 50+ producer instances were created. Like I don't want flood our app with so many producer instances .Liked for my use case I can have max 10 transaction initiated at a time.

Comment: Ok. There is currently no limit to the cache size. It would be unusual to have a lot of producers, unless you are using consumer initiated transactions with an old broker < 2.5.

Comment: Also, for producer initiated transactions, if you have multiple app instances, the transaction id prefix must be unique on each instance.

Comment: yes I figured out that on other stack overflow question. So from application point of view I don't need to  close the producer explicitly .It's same as non-transactional code ( apart from enabling transactions ).

Comment: Right. The KafkaTemplate calls close() on the producer after the operation. With transactions, it is returned to the cache. Without transactions, the close is just ignored.

Comment: Got it. So how does Spring determines when to flush( i.e. close)  the producer instance from the cache? This is the only concern .

Comment: Read the javadocs. I copied it in my answer.